# reduceRegion not working in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to get the NDVI value for each point of my featureCollection vector. I had used reduceRegion for that in codeeditor javascript of GEE. I when i using the same function in python api of GEE, it is showing 'Unrecognized argument type to convert to a FeatureCollection'. May be some thing need to change in python api for the reducer function. Please help me in this regards.

```py
import ee

import time
import datetime
import json
from ee.batch import Export

ee.Initialize()

startyear=2018
startmonth=01
startday=01

endyear=2018
endmonth=02
endday=01
def maskS2clouds(image):
    qa = image.select('QA60');
    cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
    cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0) and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);

print("test")

boundary = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1T-XrxMki2k49fhQdhMxesWKBoyyUJiKN70pErh9z')
#print(boundary)
gtpoints = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1ZvFeFO5jHGo3VExlKNc-kdL-3hmJSeyfLzqLvHhy')
print (gtpoints)
image = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').
         filterBounds(boundary).
         filterDate(datetime.datetime(startyear,startmonth,startday),
                     datetime.datetime(endyear,endmonth,endday)).
         sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESMENT").
         map(maskS2clouds). 
         limit(20))

mosaic = image.mosaic();
    #median = mosaic.median();
palette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];
clip = mosaic.clip(boundary)
#median = clip.median()
#print(clip)
ndvi = clip.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
NDVI=ndvi.multiply(100).uint8()
#print(clip)
palette = ','.join(palette)
vis = {'min': 0, 'max': 300, 'bands':'nd', 'palette': palette}
toexport = NDVI.visualize(**vis).addBands(NDVI);
#print(toexport,'toexport')
points_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegions({
  'collection':gtpoints,
  'reducer':ee.Reducer.first(),
  'scale':10
})
properties = ee.Feature(points_ndvi.first()).propertyNames()
new_names = properties.replace('first', 'ndvi')
points_ndvi = points_ndvi.select(properties, new_names)
print(points_ndvi,"test")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use dictionaries of arguments in python; python has it's own way of doing keyword arguments for that:

```
points_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegions(
  collection=gtpoints,
  reducer=ee.Reducer.first(),
  scale=10
)
```

(also, you don't need to use datetime):

```
.filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear,startmonth,startday),
            ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear,endmonth,endday))
```